# Unity - UI координаты отличаются в скрипте и на сцене

Tags: unity3d

В общем, мне нужно создать текст и кнопки с помощью скрипта, я позиционирую их на сцене как надо и записываю координаты. Затем пишу эти координаты в скрипте:

```
rectTransform.localPosition = new Vector3(542, 35, 0);
```

Но в игре элементы генерируются вообще где то, например, в `128, 253, 0`. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде вы изменяете `localPosition` объекта, то есть его положение *относительно родительского элемента* в иерархии объектов на сцене. Когда вы выбираете объект на сцене, то окне Inspector вы можете видеть `position` - положение объекта *в мировых координатах*, независимо от иерархии элементов.

Соответственно, когда вы в коде изменяете `localPosition`, относительно этих изменений пересчитывается и `position`, но в большинстве случаев, они не будут совпадать.

Не совсем понятно, какого результата вы хотите добиться, по этому поясню, что есть еще [RectTransform.anchoredPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) - позиция объекта, *относительно его якоря.

Попробуйте заменить `rectTransform.localPosition` в вашем коде на `rectTransform.position` или `rectTransform.anchoredPosition`